# InputField ActionSupport: Make Field No Longer Required

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a picklist with certain values that make another field required. I am trying to get the field required value to rerender when the picklist value changes, but no luck so far. I have tried adding a blank action to the `actionSupport` tag to no avail.

Page Snippet:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!someAccount.someField}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="otherFieldRequired" />
</apex:inputField>
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="otherFieldRequired">
    <apex:outputLabel value="Other Field Required?" />
    <apex:outputText value="{!IF(isOtherFieldRequired, 'Yes', 'No')}" />
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Controller Snippet:

```
public static Set<String> requiredPicklistValues = new Set<String> { 'A', 'B', 'C' };
public Account someAccount {get; set;}
public Boolean isOtherFieldRequired { get { return requiredPicklistValues.contains(someAccount.someField); } }
```

Comment: Did you try enclosing the pageblock inside of an outputPanel with the id as otherFieldRequired? I know it is usually a pain in the keister about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to create a property in the controller to let the page know whether or not the field is required.  You set that property int he action of the actionSupport, and then rerender.

VF Page

```
<apex:inputField value="{!someAccount.someField}">
     <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!checkRequired}" reRender="otherFieldRequired" />
</apex:inputField>
<apex:outputPanel id="otherFieldRequired">
     <apex:inputField id="dependentField" required="{!isRequired}"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Controller

```
public boolean isRequired  {get;set;}{isRequired=false;}

public PageReference checkRequired(){
     //Your logic to check if the appropriate pick list values have been set for the input field
     if(//your check){
          isRequired = true;
     }
}
```

Comment: Adrian, did you try this?

Comment: I have similar problem.
I can't make second field not required if I set the first value to value different from the list.

Comment: It seems it is impossible to make field "Not required" dynamically once it was marked as "required". Dumb visualforce

Comment: @Patlatus Yep it seems once required, always required. Unfortunate.

Comment: Actually I have been playing with javascript, trying to mark field as required or unmark. Also I am thinking now, if Chris example might work in case if we surround first <apex:inputField> with <apex:actionRegion> tag

Comment: It seems like it is now possible for `VisualForce` to understand that a field is "no longer required" across all versions, so I cannot reproduce this issue. For reference, [Jim Mitchell](http://jimmitchell.org/making-a-field-appear-required-on-a-visualforce-page/) detailed a workaround to *Make a Field Appear Required on a Visualforce Page*. Then I was able to just toggle the visibility of the required block.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I am just working on this same issue, but what has SF changed about VF? If I give an input field a `required` param with logic dependent on another field's value, I can't rerender that inputfield to make it unrequired. Your link to Jim Mitchell's page is dead BTW.

Comment: @AdrianLarson haha saw your comment date but thought it was today, not a year ago! Sorry about the resurrecting the dead thread.

Comment: @smohyee no problem there. Maybe they didn't fix it and I just used different repro.